# Error setting PlotArea.Width in Excel, VBA (Excel 2010)

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am experiencing an error in a subroutine attempting to set the plotarea.width property of a chart.

[image]

The other dimensions also cause this error if I comment out the preceding line(s).
There is no ActiveChart, no selection, etc. The specific error message is this: "-2147467259 (80004005) Method 'Width' of object 'PlotArea' failed"

This is stumping me for several reasons:

- In debug mode, F8 to step through the code the error does NOT occur.
- AFAIK "width" is not a "method" but a "property" of the chart's plotarea, so even the error message is rather ambiguous.

Any thoughts?  Here's as much code as I can share, the ChartSizeMedium subroutine in its entirety, and a dummy snippet to show you how I am establishing the chart and passing it to that sub which sets the size & some other properties prior to passing to another function which adds the series data to the chart.

```
    Option Explicit
    Private Sub EstablishChartObject()
    Dim cObj as ChartObject
    Set cObj = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=30, Top:30, Width:=740, Height:=300)
        ChartSizeMedium cObj.Chart, "Integer", "Example Chart Title"
    End Sub
    Private Sub ChartSizeMedium(cht As Chart, NumType As String, Optional chtTitle As String)
    'Subroutine to make a consistent size chart
    Dim s As Long
    With cht
    'Add a chart title if one exists.
        If Len(chtTitle) > 0 Then
        .HasTitle = True
        .chartTitle.Characters.Text = chtTitle
        End If
    'Create the default chart Legend
        .HasLegend = True
        With .Legend
        .Position = xlTop
        .Font.Size = 11
        .Font.Bold = True
        End With
    'Format the axes
        .Axes(xlValue).MajorGridlines.Format.Line.Visible = msoFalse
        .Axes(xlValue).MinorGridlines.Format.Line.Visible = msoFalse

    'Format the size of the chart
        With .Parent
        .Width = 740
        .Height = 396
        End With

        With .PlotArea
        .Width = 640    '<---- THIS LINE TRIGGERS THE ERROR
        .Height = 280
        .Left = 30
        .Top = 30
        End With
    End With
    'Some charts start with more than one series container, so make sure they're gone:
    With cht
    Do Until .SeriesCollection.Count = 0
    s = .SeriesCollection.Count
    .SeriesCollection(s).Delete
    Loop
    End With
    End Sub
```

**UPDATE Dec 12, 2012**

I remove all non-problematic code and use only the PlotArea with block, in the same routine, I have also tried setting the chart type (several values) and as shown in this example, manually adding one series of data prior to attempting to set the PlotArea dimensions, but the error persists:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub EstablishChartObject2()
    Dim cObj As ChartObject
    Dim sh As Worksheet

    Set sh = ActiveSheet
    Dim srs As Series
    Set cObj = sh.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=30, Top:=30, Width:=740, Height:=300)
    Set srs = cObj.Chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries

    srs.Values = "={1,3,5,7,4}"
    cObj.Chart.ChartType = 57

    With cObj.Chart.PlotArea
        .Width = 100   '<---- THIS LINE TRIGGERS THE ERROR
        .Height = 280
        .Left = 30
        .Top = 30
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: just throwing this out there, does it occur for certain chart types? maybe 1 that does not have a plot area (if that even exists... )

Comment: @ScottHoltzman thanks for the suggestion but by default, ChartType is 57 (xlBarClustered) which definitely does have a PlotArea :)  

`Debug.Print cObj.Chart.PlotArea.Width`

returns a plotarea.width of 718.

Comment: This thread discusses a similar problem and a refresh timing issue: http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/746724-method-width-of-object-plotarea-failed.html. You have to log in to see Andy Pope's solution, so I don't know what it is, but since it Andy's I'm sure it works. This thread says that they solved it by turning `ScreenUpdating` back on: http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-17251.html. Don't know if that applies to you.

Comment: can you comment this `width` line to see if error jumps any other line?

Comment: @DougGlancy ScreenUpdating=True in this sub already, so it's not an issue of turning it back on (temporarily) although I had seen that suggestion when trying to google the error, and tried playing with ScreenUpdating to no avail.

Comment: @bonCodigo Yes, if I comment out the `width` then the error jumps to the `.height` on the next line. The error code & message is identically ambiguous. Does that help you at all?

I seem to be able to circumvent this by Selecting the plot plot area and then de-selecting immediately afterwards (and the error does not jump to the `height` when I do this) but I was hoping this could be done without making a "selection".

Comment: Voila! Then if you keep commenting, what happens, where does the error hang on to finally? And oh please do not `select`. It seems programme is *losing touch* of your `plot area` at some point. :( I am going to post something in the answer to try out. Please comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two solutions that seem to be working, neither is really as "elegant" as I'd prefer (I was hoping there would be a way to do this with *selecting* the chart or any part of it).

**Option 1 - Select the plot area and then deselect it.**  This seems to be the most reliable/efficient solution.

```
With .PlotArea
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   .Select
    With Selection
        .Width = paWidth
        .Height = paHeight
        .Left = paLeft
        .Top = paTop
        ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Activate
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End With
```

**Option 2 - disable error-handling in loop** (this followed from Doug's link). This doesn't seem to be a very reliable or efficient method, and although it seems to work, I *know* that within that loop it is failing once on each of the properties before it successfully sets them on a subsequent pass.

```
With .PlotArea
    For pLoop = 1 To 5
        On Error Resume Next
        .Width = paWidth
        .Height = paHeight
        .Left = paLeft
        .Top = paTop
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next
End With
```

Comment: Btw you may add your trials here to your question by appending it. And it is also advisable that you DO NOT CHANGE ORIGINAL POST unless otherwise commented as lack of info. Keep you original post and opened updates below it with e.g. update 1, 2.

Answer (score 5):

i had a  similar problem . And its definitely an excel issue (having 2013).

```
With .PlotArea 
    .Select 'err if delete this line of code
    .Top = 0
    .Left = 0
    .width = 40
    .Height = 40 
End With
```

if you remove the `.select`line, it will result in error on the next line.
note that i am not working with a <`with selection`do stuff>.
the `.select`makes it work, without using the selection, wich is obviously an excel bug (from previous versions?)

Comment: I am using Excel 2010 and your solution helped me as well.

Comment: same here with Excel 2016. It helped :)

Answer (score 1):

Hope your sheet and chart has the ability to get a width up to `640`. If so try the **explicit** reference. Also suggest you to change `width, height` values to lower values and see how programme responds. Since you said, when you `select` it works,

- that also means, your `cht` is wrapping the correct chart object - unless otherwise you selected the chart using `ActiveChart.PlotArea.Width` . Hence I guess explicit reference could do be a potential try out.

,

```
cht.PlotArea.Width = 640
cht.PlotArea.Height = 280
cht.PlotArea.Left = 30
cht.PlotArea.Top = 30
```

Further, check on `Aspect Ratio` lock or unlock. If none of these works, then add a chart into your sheet and use most simple chart formatting code to check on `widht, height, left, top` changes.

---

### Update two

Let's try specifing chart type and setting up chart object in the second `sub` as well. I tried out in my end and it's working. Try the code with following changes.

Code:
Calling this sub from the button showed in the sheet.

```
Option Explicit

  Public Sub EstablishChartObject()
  Dim mySheet As Worksheet
  Dim cObj As ChartObject

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.StatusBar = "Chart is coming soon..."

    Set mySheet = Sheets(2) '-- set according to yours
    '-- create chart with some source data first, which you can change later
    Set cObj = mySheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=30, Top:=30, Width:=400, Height:=200)
    ChartSizeMedium cObj, "Integer", "Example Chart Title"
        
  End Sub


  'Subroutine to make a consistent size chart
  Private Sub ChartSizeMedium(chtObj As ChartObject, NumType As String, _
                                  Optional chtTitle As String)
    
  Dim myChart As Chart
  Dim s As Long
    
     Set myChart = chtObj.Chart '-- specify chart type
     myChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets(2).Range("B3:C12")  '-- set to what you have
     myChart.ChartType = xlXYScatterLines  '-- set to the type you want 
                                          'and make sure to **use correct properties**

        With myChart
            If .HasTitle Then
                .ChartTitle.Characters.Text = chtTitle
            End If
        
            'Create the default chart Legend
            If .HasLegend Then
                With .Legend
                    .Position = xlTop
                    .Font.Size = 11
                    .Font.Bold = True
                End With
            End If
            
            'Format the axes
            With .Axes(xlValue)
                .HasMajorGridlines = False
            End With
                    
            'Format the size of the chart
            With .Parent
                .Width = 400 '-- change to yours
                .Height = 250 '-- change to yours
            End With
    
            With .PlotArea
                .Width = 300 '-- change to yours
                .Height = 180 '-- change to yours
                .Left = 30
                .Top = 30
            End With
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.StatusBar = "Chart is Here!"

End Sub
```

Otput:

[image]

**Make sure to use correct properties for each chart type.** Note that above code doesn't delete any left over, old charts from your sheet.

`.MajoreGridlines.Format.Lines.Visible` fails. So set the `.MajorGridlines = False` to make sure you do not want to show the gridlines.
Anything else you want to do can be done later. **Just try with the changes to dimension initially.**

Reference from : [MSDN Gridlines property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa174226%28v=office.11%29.aspx)

Comment: I can't lowercase it, the VBA editor automatically reformats to proper case "Width" etc.

Aspect ratio is unlocked by default when creating chart object.

I try to isolate the error, it happens on all four dimensions (width, height, top, left) if I comment out the other lines.

the error persists even with explicit references to `cht.PlotArea.Width...`

Comment: I didn't mean lowercase at all David... 1. Did you comment out all 4 properties: left, top, height, width? 2. Does the error persist? 3. Do you see any chart object is created at all? 4. Are there more than one chart you create? 5. Can you get the "system" name of the chart you are adding? Where do you declare your `cObj`?

Comment: Sorry, misread the "lower"

If 1=Yes, then 2=No. The error occurs on ALL of the dimension properties of the PlotArea unless I SELECT the plotarea.

3 - Yes. And ?cobj.Chart.PlotArea.Width returns a default width larger than 640. I have tried width as small as 250 to the same error.

4 - Persists no matter how many charts exist on sheet.

5 - Not sure what this means.

6 - see OP for declaration of cObj

Comment: Do you have `option explicit` in your code? I don't see `Dim cObj as chart`

Comment: I had accidentally omitted that from the snippet I pasted in to this query, but yes, I do have `Option Explicit` as line 1 in the code module followed by some `Public Const` declarations and then the subroutines receive aggregate data from a Python/com object and construct and format the charts. I think doing this sort of app without Explicit would've been asking for trouble. :)

Comment: @DavidZemens check the latest update. I managed to get a hold of sometime to try your code out. It doesn't seem to have many erros. However setting the sheet and setting chart type could be the trick here. Plus as mentioned there was an error in your gridlines disabling code. Happy to hear your comments.

Comment: This is the proper Gridlines syntax for 2010 but it would fail in 2003.  I test the same routine on 2003 and the 'width' error does not occur, so you may not be able to replicate it.

I have tried setting charttype &/or adding series data prior to passing to the formatting macro, to no avail.

I remove everything except PlotArea with block in the formatting sub, and the error persists. I also move that block in to the EstablishChartObject sub, so I'm no longer passing anything between subs, but still get the error in 2010 (but not in 2003).

Comment: @DavidZemens Well well, **this code is in 2003 MS Excel**. And I have tested out in 2010 as well. Only 2007 is omitted as it is one horrible version. I even grabbed another pc near by to try out for any other code transfer issues. Nothing of that sort. So if this helps, please mark up the answer :)

Comment: I believe the update I added to the OP this morning incorporates your suggested changes, and to simplify things I put only the offending with block in the the same sub that creates the chartobject.

This code continues to fail for me, at the same point. If it works for you, I will have to assume something on my local machine is causing the failure.

**Possibly worth noting** this chart does NOT use source data contained in the worksheet, the series data is added programmatically from a another sub that receives variant array data from a Python object.

Comment: Then add the array data and test from a different machine.

Comment: Even if I assign series values the error persists (see update from this morning where I assign a series to the chart prior to formatting).

It's been tested on two different machines; 32b and 64b Windows 7, Office Pro, Excel 2010 and reliably fails on both.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, and this solution seems bad, but it works. I only thought to do it as you mention that stepping through works.

```
Option Explicit

Sub chart()

Dim cObj As ChartObject
Dim sh As Worksheet

Set sh = ActiveSheet
Dim srs As Series
Set cObj = sh.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=30, Top:=30, Width:=740, Height:=300)
cObj.chart.ChartType = 57
Set srs = cObj.chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    srs.Values = "={1,3,5,7,4}"
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01") '<~~ Added This line
With cObj.chart.PlotArea
    .Width = 100
    .Height = 280
    .Left = 30
    .Top = 30
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Great! The application is now entirely in PPT but the same error was happening. I had to modify this a little bit to use `Timer` since PPT does not have an `Application.Wait`. I have tested this instead of my clumsy solution, and it seems to be working correctly with a 1 second pause.

Comment: You may even be able to shorten it to quarter a second or half even, i didn't experiment to much but if you feel the 1 second seems slower then what you already had in place, or just would like to make it faster you can always try and shorten the wait/timer.

Comment: I was able to modify this slightly and put the pause inside an error trap that will retry and increment the wait time in .5 second intervals. This *seems* to be working for now. Thanks for the suggestion!!

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** This seems to work for *some* chart types, but it was still failing for other chart types. I have continued to use the 5x loop with `On Error Resume Next` and that seems to be -- unfortunately -- the most "reliable" solution to-date.

**Original**:  This is based on User2140261's suggested answer, above:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16041640/1467082

Since the question was initially posted, the application now resides in PowerPoint, so I cannot use the `Applicaiton.Wait`.  I had some intermittent errors with a 1-second pause, and 3-seconds was too much of a pause, so I built the following error trap.  The same idea could be used in Excel in conjunction with `Application.Wait`.

It was this block of code that was giving me fits, so I added this error handling in Powerpoint to mimic the `Application.Wait`.

```
RetryChartDimensions:
On Error GoTo ErrChartDimensions
With .PlotArea
    .Width = paWidth
    .Height = paHeight
    .Left = paLeft
    .Top = paTop
End With
On Error GoTo 0

' More code
' more code

Exit Sub 'gracefully exit this subroutine before the error-handling.'

ErrChartDimensions:
Err.Clear
'Pause before setting the PlotArea dimensions:'
Dim wtTime As Double
Dim startTime As Long

'A maximum 3 second delay should be more than enough time.
If wtTime < 3 Then
    wtTime = wtTime + 0.5
    startTime = Timer
    While Timer < startTime + wtTime
        DoEvents
    Wend
End If
Resume RetryChartDimensions

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to add a comment, so using the above solutions I have fixed my problem with Pie Charts in VB.Net 2010 and Excel 2013. xlLine charts never caused a problem, but my code would crash when the same code was ran against an xlPie chart on Excel 2013 (All was fine on Excel 2007).

My now working code:

```
    appExcel.Visible = False
    xlchart_for_96_Well_Plate_Source = appExcel.Charts.Add(After:=wkbExperiment_Details.Sheets(wkbExperiment_Details.Sheets.Count))
    appExcel.ScreenUpdating = False

    With xlchart_for_96_Well_Plate_Source
            .SetSourceData(Source:=wksData.Range(wksData.Cells(2, byteCharts_added), wksData.Cells(intUsed_Rows, byteCharts_added)), PlotBy:=Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlRowCol.xlColumns)
            .ChartType = objChart_Type
            .PlotArea.Select() 
            .PlotArea.Top = 2
            .PlotArea.Select()
            .PlotArea.Left = 2
            .SeriesCollection(.SeriesCollection.count).xvalues = wksData.Range(wksData.Cells(2, 1), wksData.Cells(intUsed_Rows, 1)).Value ' Scale - wavelength for line chart
            .SeriesCollection(.SeriesCollection.count).Values = wksData.Range(wksData.Cells(2, byteCharts_added + 1), wksData.Cells(intUsed_Rows, byteCharts_added + 1)).Value
            .SeriesCollection(.SeriesCollection.count).Name = wksData.Cells(1, .SeriesCollection.count + 1).value
    End With
appExcel.ScreenUpdating = True
```