# Excel - Fill a cell with different colors

Tags: vba, excel

I need to fill a cell with different colors as in this picture (3 rows are merged vertically and colors are drawn manually in this picture using 3 rectangular shapes):

[image: Fill cell with different colors]

The only way I could find to fill part of a cell is using conditional formatting (by setting style as data bar and fill as solid) but it support only one color.
Is this possible with or without VBA?

Comment: as far as i know this is not possible in Excel, not easy at least. But try looking at the Ring Diagramm type. it would be a easy solution.

Comment: Thanks @DoktorOSwaldo, I couldn't find any any way so far. how can I add the Ring Diagram to a cell? I know it is possible to add line or column plot to a cell using sparklines but I wonder if it is possible with Ring Diagram as well.

Comment: you can't directly add it to a cell, but you can set the cell as left and top. Look at ChartObjects.Add -> With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=Range("I5").Left, _
 Top:=Range("I5").Top, _
and so on

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo, thanks. I have found 2 solutions for my problem and posted as response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible.

I have found two ways to do that.

1- Using a black square shaped character (character code 2588 – vba: ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1) = ChrW(&H2588)) and color them according to percentage. This character fills the cell height and also there is no spacing between them which allows filling a cell completely (Sure you should consider left indent in a cell). Only issue here that you cannot use a lot of characters in one cell; I use 30 of them and scale the number of characters according to 30 (ie. 50% red means 15 red character-2588).

2- It is same as what @Doktor Oswaldo has suggested: Inserting a plot in a cell using cell's position and size in pixels. This method has one big advantage: you can show the ratios exactly. In addition, you can fill a data series with a pattern as well. However if you have a lot of plots, you will sacrifice from Excel performance. For plot settings, I use following VBA code:

```
    'Define var's
Dim src As Range, targetCell As Range
Dim chacha As ChartObject

'Set var's
Set src = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1:B3")
Set targetCell = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C2")

'Create plot at the target cell
Set chacha = Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects.Add(targetCell.Left, targetCell.Top, targetCell.Width, targetCell.Height)

'Change plot settings to fill the cell
With chacha.Chart
    .ChartType = xlBarStacked
    .SetSourceData Source:=src, PlotBy:=xlRows
    .Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = 0
    .Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = 100
    .Axes(xlCategory).Delete
    .Axes(xlValue).Delete
    .Legend.Delete
    .PlotArea.Top = -50
    .PlotArea.Left = -50
    .PlotArea.Width = targetCell.Width
    .PlotArea.Height = targetCell.Height
    .ChartGroups(1).GapWidth = 0
End With

chacha.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
chacha.Chart.SeriesCollection(2).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 255)
chacha.Chart.SeriesCollection(3).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 0)
```

In the code I modified the series colors manually which can also be automatized. Following is the screenshot of both methods. The Cell "C1" is filled with block characters and "C2" is a chart.

[image: FillCellPlot]

Note: You might get an error at the line ".PlotArea.Top". To solve this issue, please check: [Error setting PlotArea.Width in Excel, VBA (Excel 2010)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13812491/error-setting-plotarea-width-in-excel-vba-excel-2010)