# Error occurred during set PlotArea.Width in powerPoint, VBA (powerpoint macro 2016)

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I'm getting - Method `InsideHeight` of object `PlotArea` failed in PowerPoint 2016. below code working perfectly in old Office version but when I updated my Office version then its showing error.

Error occurred during set chart plotArea propertys link hight, width, left etc. in VBA 2016:
[image: error occurred during set chart plotArea propertys link hight,width,left etc. in vba 2016]

My Code example :

```
With .Chart
    .ChartGroups(1).GapWidth = 90
    .ChartGroups(1).Overlap = 100
    .PlotArea.Select
    .PlotArea.InsideHeight = 450
    .PlotArea.InsideWidth = 280
    .PlotArea.width = 500
    .PlotArea.left = 5
    .PlotArea.top = 10
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13812491/error-setting-plotarea-width-in-excel-vba-excel-2010 . Did you look at this question?

Comment: Excel or Powerpoint??